# Present a blurred UIViewController on top of another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have 2 VCs - `firstVC` and `secondVC`.
`secondVC`'s view's color is `clear color` and it has a `UIVisualEffect` view with dark blur.

I want to present `secondVC` modally on `firstVC` but when I do that, `firstVC` becomes black.

Thank you

Comment: which iOS are you using ? and are you running on iPhone or iPad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `modalPresentationStyle` appropriately on the *presented* (secondVC) controller.

`UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` or `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` will provide the effect of the second VC's content over the top of the first VC.

Answer (score 1):

if ios version >= 8.0 then

```
 SecondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:SecondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

if using ios7 & navigation controller then

```
 self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:SecondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

if there is no navigation controller then

```
 self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:SecondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```